# Running guest Ubuntu in VirtualBox with a custom resolution

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu

I know similar questions have been asked before about setting the VirtualBox guest resolution, but I haven't been able to find an answer to my custom case.

I've installed VirtualBox on my Windows 7 laptop, and I'm trying to run Kubuntu as a guest.
The windows resolution is 1366x768, and I'd like to have Kubuntu use the same resolution when in full-screen mode.

I have successfully installed the Guest Additions package. 
This lets me configure various high resolutions, but none of them are 1366x768.

I'd like to know if it is possible to add such a custom resolution to Kubuntu.
In the old days, it was possible to edit xorg.conf, but I guess that file is no longer created.

I also tried to run "VBoxManage.exe controlvm Kubuntu 1366 768 32" from the host, but this didn't seem to do anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of VBox are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i have the additions loaded for my linux virtuals, once I have kde running, the screen automatically resize to whatever size I change the window to.  So if I go to full screen, i would assume it goes to the full resolution.

Does your virtual resize automatically?

[Have you seen this thread?](http://forum.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&p=168811)

\\Greg

Comment: it does, but not to full-screen. When I go to full-screen I get a two black margins, and the kubuntu in the middle at 1024x768. Note - my screen height is 768.

Comment: I edited my answer to add a link to a vbox forum thread

Comment: great! this post http://forum.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=37614&sid=1b32aae79fdfef8cc08801cb7c43578c#p169100 worked. thank you.